# Is there an R function to get the number of permutations of n objects take k P(n,k)?

Tags: r, permutation, combinations

..or do I have to give

```
P.nk <- factorial(n) / factorial(n-k)
```

or

```
P.nk <- choose(n,k) * factorial(k)
```

Thank you.

Comment: As others have said, there is a straight permutations function in gregmisc (gtools in the new parsed gregmisc packages).  But, that and all other package functions I've found are really for generating permutations, not for just giving the total number of permutations.  Therefore, they tend to be slow.

I've benchmarked just such functions before.  Your option 2 here is far and away the fastest, much faster than any package functions I've found.  It also has a higher upper limit for calculations than your first option.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know of any existing function. Your first suggestion will fail with large n. Your second idea should work fine when written as a function:

```
perm <- function(n,k){choose(n,k) * factorial(k)}
```

Then `perm(500,2)` will give 249500 for example.

Comment: First suggestion could be rewrite as `exp(lfactorial(n) - lfactorial(n-k))`. But I will use second too.

Answer (score 3):

I think the [*gregmisc*](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gregmisc/index.html) package provides these functions.

```
library(gregmisc)
permutations(n=4,r=4)
```

Mailing list reference:  [[R] permutation](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-November/027330.html)

Comment: Actually, what is asked would be given by: dim(permutations(n,k))[1]

Comment: package ‘gregmisc’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3) Jun 4, 2019

Answer (score 2):

Check out `nsamp(n,k,ordered=T)` in the 'prob' package

Comment: `nsamp(500,2,ordered=TRUE)` encounter problem state in Rob answer (`value out of range`).

Comment: > nsamp(173,2,ordered=TRUE)
`[1] NaN
Warning messages:
1: In factorial(n[i]) : value out of range in 'gammafn'
2: In factorial(n[i] - k[i]) : value out of range in 'gammafn'`
> nsamp(171,2,ordered=TRUE)
`[1] Inf
Warning message:
In factorial(n[i]) : value out of range in 'gammafn'`
> nsamp(170,2,ordered=TRUE)
`[1] 28730`

----R version 3.5.3

Answer (score 1):

Another way for doing that, from Base R is

```r
permn <- prod( (n-(0:(k-1)))
```

that is a simple implementation of the following formula

$$p(n,k) = \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} n-j$$

Answer (score 0):

package `gtools`

```
# R version 3.5.3
install.packages("gtools")
library(gtools)

base::nrow(gtools::permutations(500,2))
```

result:

`[1] 249500`

also see [combinations-and-permutations-in-r](https://davetang.org/muse/2013/09/09/combinations-and-permutations-in-r/), [permutation_with_replacement.R](https://gist.github.com/davetang/6485079#file-permutation_with_replacement-r)

another package `prob`:

`base::ncol(prob::permsn(500,2))`

`[1] 249500`

Comment: these options are really for generating permutations so will be really slow if all you need is the number of permutations