# All possible combinations for large numbers in R

Tags: r, combinations

Image i have a sequence like this:

```
seq <- rep(0:9, 10)
```

I want to know all possible combinations of this sequence. For sure, command `combn` isn't working:

```
> comb <- combn(seq, 10)
Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) : 
  invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning message:
In combn(seq, 10) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

Can you give me a hint how to make my own function for all possible combinations?

Comment: There are 10^10 possible combinations, that is probably why it is giving the error.

Comment: @Lesley , do you mean all combinations of the vector  c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) ?

Comment: @ytk, absolutely yes, and would be nice to avoid this problem. Unfortunately, I don't know how and need  a little push to keep going.

Comment: @Koba, yes. I have to get all possible numbers from 0 to 9, for example:
1234567890
3216549870 and so on...

Comment: That should be permutations instead of combinations. package `gtools`. `gtools::permutations(10,10,0:9)` # R version 3.5.3 [is-there-an-r-function-to-get-the-number-of-permutations-of-n-objects-take-k-pn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871763/is-there-an-r-function-to-get-the-number-of-permutations-of-n-objects-take-k-pn/56436850#56436850)

or package `prob`. `prob::permsn(0:9,10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your reply to the comment , here is one thing you can do . You need the combinat package installed for this to work.

```
library(combinat)
seq <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
permn(seq)
```